# How can I locate a link that is a child of the following sibling?

Tags: java, playwright, playwright-java

I have to colour an element after the selection, the element which i would like to colour is found as a child of the following sibling.

I have successfully located the element using the following code

```
page.getByRole(AriaRole.COMBOBOX, new Page.GetByRoleOptions().setName("* Legal Type"))
```

How can I go to the following sibling from this element and then locate the child of that following-sibling?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are better ways to solve this. But I think you will need to use an XPath locator.

```
Locator combo = page.getByRole(AriaRole.COMBOBOX, new Page.GetByRoleOptions().setName("* Legal Type"));
Locator child = combo.locator("xpath=./following-sibling::*/*");
```

- `./following-sibling::*` Will give you the sibling. no matter the tag name (`*`).
- `/*` will give you the child, no matter the tag name.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for writing up, I am getting this error `com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: Error {
  message='Unexpected token "/" while parsing selector "./following-sibling::*/*"`

Comment: Could you try with the new change?

Comment: I tried, but now it's not locating the element. This code works   `Locator child = combo.locator("xpath=//label[text()='Legal Type']/following-sibling::div/a");` But when I try to locate by this way, it's selecting the option but it's not colouring and failing.       `Locator combo = page.getByRole(AriaRole.COMBOBOX, new Page.GetByRoleOptions().setName("* Legal Type"));
        Locator child = combo.locator("xpath=.//following-sibling::div/a");
        child.evaluate("el => el.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'");`